# How can I make a fieldset legend-style "background line" on heading text?

Tags: css, header, legend, fieldset

I'm attempting to style heading text similar to how your [default legend text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset) appears in fieldsets; that is to say, I'd like a strikethrough-like line to come up to, but not through, the text.  I can't seem to find any information on how I might accomplish this, and since on numerous other questions Google's always directed me to Stack Overflow for answers, I thought someone here may be able to give me advice.

For greater clarity. I'm attempting to get this effect on header text:

Centered Header Text

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Specifically, do you care about IE7?

Comment: No, IE8+ is as low as the site will need to go.

Comment: I mean, IE7 would be nice, but if it gets in the way of a small feature like this, I'm not going to complain.

Comment: It is interesting that there are 9 answers but none of them is answering the question since none works with <legend> inside <fieldset> that behaves different to <h2>.

Comment: @Jörg Perhaps my question was poorly-phrased; I wasn't actually trying to style `<legend>` elements, but (as most of the answers surmised) style header text to look like `<legend>` elements do inside `<fieldset>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jm4VQ/

If the text needs to wrap, this won't work. In IE7, there will be no line.

**HTML:**

```
<h2><span>Centered Header Text</span></h2>
```

**CSS:**

```css
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 > span, h2:before, h2:after {
    display: table-cell;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/2x1/f0f/fff&text=+) repeat-x center;
    width: 50%;
    content: ' ';
}
h2 > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0 9px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported in Opera (10.63) either.

Comment: Well, :before/:after work in Opera, so I'm not sure what the cause is.  Quite possibly, Opera doesn't like the application of excessive styles to :before/:after, but I'm not sure why.  However, your fix seems to work nicely once I remove the 100% attribute from the header (since that causes it to malfunction with floating elements).  Thank you! :D

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

```
<h2><strike>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strike>Your Text Here<strike>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strike></h2>
```

Here's how you can do it with a few simple tags and non-breaking spaces.

I'd use an image and call it a day, but this seemed to work for me:

### CSS

```
  fieldset {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  legend {
    margin: 0 25%;
  }
```

### HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>My Text Here</legend>
</fieldset>
```

That's the only way I could figure out how to do it with css. Note the width is fixed. Once again I wouldn't do this myself.

[image: CSS Cat Does Not Approve]

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a quick, image-less solution that seems to work pretty well in IE 8+ and other browsers, whilst gracefully degrading in IE 6/7:

```html
<h1>CSS 2.1 EXAMPLE</h1>
```

```css
h1 { position: relative; text-align: center; }
h1:first-line { background-color: white; }
h1:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 1px;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

It does come with the following limitations, though:

- The text must match the overall background colour exactly, otherwise it will look weird.
- If you want any kind of padding on the text, you need to use non-breaking spaces at either side of the text (see demo).
- Heading text must always be on one line (works best if fixed width).

**Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/3tFQJ/​**

Answer (score 2):

With flexbox being supported by all the latest browsers out there, and it being five years since the IE8 requirement was mentioned by the author, I wanted to have some fun building a new solution using that.

A variety of examples getting more complicated:

https://jsfiddle.net/0mL79b4h/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/0mL79b4h/2/

## CSS

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 2px;

  display: block;

  content: "";
  flex: 1;

  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;

  margin: 8px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>Example Text</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Multi-Line<br>Example Text</h1>
</div>
```

Pros:

- Uses flexbox!
- Super simple HTML.
- Left and right sides can be adjusted for asymmetry.
- Zero background issues, no inheriting colors, etc.
- Fluid width.
- Multi-Line support.
- Left/Center/Right/Custom Alignment: Just adjust the flex property separately for the before and after elements, higher numbers will dedicate more space to that side. Remove one entirely to left or right align it.
- Interesting effects by playing with the border style (I actually chose a round border in this example). Set height to 0px and use border-top instead for a generic line.

Cons:

- Uses flexbox. Call me lazy, but I didn't build in any backward compatibility in this example so it'll look odd on a browser that supports psuedo elements but doesn't support flexbox, although last I checked that was Chrome (Firefox, etc), which are all automatically updated anyway. Might want to use some Modernizr.

Comment: very nice solution, shortest and very precise no need to inherit colors as you said! 

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am using on a client's site: http://jsfiddle.net/TPgE4/

Pros:

- No images needed - renders instantly
- Uses padding to control space on both sides of text
- Text can be center aligned, or left/right aligned — just add, e.g.,  `margin-left: 8px` or `margin-right: 8px` on `h2 span` style definition to make it look good

Cons:

- Requires use of additional tag such as `<span>...</span>` inside heading tag
- Text must fit on one line for good appearance
- Background color on `<span>` element must match surrounding background color, so if you have a non-solid background image, gradient or pattern it won't match perfectly

Comment: Left-aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/TPgE4/4/ Right-aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/TPgE4/5/

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late to the party, but this is my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/g43pt908/

Requires no images, and doesn't depend on a background color.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hr-text">
    <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hr-text {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.hr-text span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 14px;
    top: -12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #666;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! The one problem I potentially see with this is that if it needed to be on a `background-image`, I think it would need to be used with a `fixed` attachment to make sure the image in the `span` lines up with its container's. Where that's not an issue, though, this is definitely the cleanest solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would suit your need...

```
h1:before, h1:after {
 content: " ------------- ";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it wouldn't stretch to the edge of the document.  Something similar may be able to be done with JavaScript, but I'd worry about cross-browser issues (not to mention my desire to keep the site as JS-free as possible, due to my usual over-reliance on it).

Comment: Giving it another go: http://jsfiddle.net/4BZVt/

This one is centred and spans across the document width.

Comment: That's a very innovative approach, but it has the same problem as thirtydot's (with an image background, it's impossible to match): http://jsfiddle.net/4BZVt/1/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't feel like a very good answer, but I'm posting it anyway.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/rFmQg/

```
<h2><span>Centered Header Text</span></h2>

h2 {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/2x1/f0f/fff&text=+) repeat-x center;
    text-align: center
}
h2 span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 9px
}
```

I don't like it because:

- You have to use an image.
- [This.](http://jsfiddle.net/rFmQg/1/) *(it only works if the backgrounds match)*

Comment: Yeah, I had considered this, but that's a big issue with me, since there's an image background.  If my site used a clean background, it would work great.

Comment: Did you see my comments on your question?

Comment: I got it, based on your answer and kei's redo! The solution was to use the image idea, with kei's redo formatting - but change it to use a table. http://jsfiddle.net/4BZVt/2/

Comment: @Meshaal: Oops. I thought by "heading text" you meant `h1`/`h2` tag, so I was working off that assumption. Yes, it's very easy to do if you're [willing](http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/) to use [`table`s for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/). My second answer is also using `table`s, just the CSS variety that don't work in IE7 and aren't unsemantic HTML. I suppose using a HTML `table` is at least simple and easy :)

Comment: @thirtydot: Well, I did mean h1/h2 etc - but in the end, I can style any text how I would headings, and as long as the same effect is achieved, I don't particularly mind a little extra code overhead to achieve the effect.  Using tables for layout has never been a preference of mine - but I'll fall back on it if necessary.

Comment: @Meshaal: Well, for what it's worth, here's how I'd probably do it using a `table`, keeping IE7 support. Yes, it's basically the same as your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QNURQ/1/ Or removing the `.line` class (still works in IE7): http://jsfiddle.net/QNURQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
body { padding-top: 100px; }

div.parent {
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.parent div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div>My Text Here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is a fluid-width solution that matches your design and should be ok in IE7 (though I'll admit I didn't check). There are a couple of downsides:

- You lose the fieldset/legend semantics.
- You can't put a transparent background on the text.

If you don't need it to be fluid-width, onteria_'s solution is probably your best bet.

Comment: You should make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code to enable people to quickly see if it will work. I can see that this has the same downside that my first answer and another answer has (the transparent background thing), and the OP has already said he can't use it.