# CSS: How to center text with surrounding borders

Tags: center, css

I am trying to center text that has a line going through the entire background. On either side of the text, there is some padding, where you cannot see the line at all. I am stumped as far as a good css-only way to go about this. Here is a jsfiddle that is obviously wrong, but its a start:  http://jsfiddle.net/gtspk/

[image]

**HTML**

```
<span class="line">
    <h2>Latest Track</h2>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.line{display:block; width:100%; border-bottom:1px solid red; margin-top:25px; text-align:center}
.line h2{font-size:15px; text-align:center; position:relative; top:10px; padding:0 15px; display:inline-block; background:white}
```

The problem here is that I DO NOT want to specify a width, because I will be reusing this for different headers (with different amounts of text). What is the best way to go about this via css?

UPDATE: HEre is a way to do it, but inline-block has fairly lousy browser support:  http://jsfiddle.net/gtspk/3/

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263163/how-can-i-put-solid-lines-on-either-side-of-a-header-with-css

Comment: There is no problem with `inline-block` support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block

Comment: your right, good point. Problem solved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go. Had to add a wrapping span (necessary so we can set the background to white so the line doesn't hit the text)

http://jsfiddle.net/gtspk/9/

```
<span class="line">
    <h2><span>Latest Track</span></h2>
</span>​

.line{display:block; margin:25px}
.line h2{font-size:15px; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid red; position:relative; }
.line h2 span { background-color: white; position: relative; top: 10px; padding: 0 10px;}
```

Right, sorry, misunderstood what you meant by padding. Fixed.​

Comment: it requires background :(