# How to make a box with borders cutting at some points

Tags: html

I'm working on a practice project and I'm facing a problem. There is a border box with the border cut off near the text and the button. I shall appreciate it if you people can tell me how to make a box like that. I tried several methods but they were not good at different viewports.

[image]

Comment: can we see some code you've tried ?

Comment: i performed multiple tries and i ended up deleting them all

Comment: [Here is something to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429633/css-how-to-center-text-with-surrounding-borders)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look. [Workinglink](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgEMM/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
 }

h1{
  width:30px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-left:5px;
  background:white;
}
```

Comment: it does not work with background: transparent and thats what i need, as you can see in the image provided

Comment: Show your code here so that anyone can see your code and fix where is the problem.I just show you how you make a box border cutting some point.I think you got my point.Thanks

Comment: Upload your transparent image in any server then give backgound image link in jsfiddle.

Comment: Your link is not a image link at all.I think you misunderstand my word. Jsfiddle `background: url(images/slider-bg-img3.jpg) no-repeat;` In the url give the right image link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it.
Using "margin" in CSS you can do it.

```
<div class="back-box">
  <div class="second-box">
    <div class="text-box">
      <h2>
         My Text here
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.back-box{ background-color: black; width: 500px; height: 200px; padding: 50px }
.second-box { border: 1px solid white; width: 500px; height: 200px }
.text-box{ background-color: black; margin-top:-30px; width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align: center }
h2 { color: white; }
```

Comment: Nice, but how to make it applicable when there is a background image?

Comment: Use -  background-image: url("paper.gif"); instead of background-color: black;

Comment: but what about the background given to the text div?