# Text inline with border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uw8p.png)

OK. so im stuck with this. If you see the image it has a heading "ROHAN JAISWAL" with "WEB DEVELOPER" text in border. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Adding a code example of what you currently have would help a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: How to center text with surrounding borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429633/css-how-to-center-text-with-surrounding-borders)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `border-top: 0;` on the box containing your name. Then replace the left and right parts of that top border with two [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) (`::before` and `::after`) on the element containing the "Web developer" text. Each of these pseudo-elements you can style with a `width`, `height`, and `background-color` the same color as the border.