# How to position text over border?

Tags: html, css

I was able to get it working with a white background:

[image]

But in cases where the background isn't white, the solution doesn't work as well:

[image]

It should be quite obvious what I did any why it doesn't work (negative margin + background set to background color). Are there any solutions to make it always look good?

Comment: Yea sure, screenshots are better than the actual CSS code `:P`

Comment: I'm asking about idea - not code (already coded idea would be useful, too).

Comment: Could you set the background to transparent for the text?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985009/how-can-i-make-a-fieldset-legend-style-background-line-on-heading-text

Comment: @AndrewHagner Yes, but it will not cover border (and won't leave that 10px gap to the left and to the right).

Comment: @rfausak I think this is what I'm looking for :) Thank you! I'm yet to test and see if it works.

Comment: http://www.impressivewebs.com/centered-heading-horizontal-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use spacer spans along with a wrapper (in this case `header`), with all elements with `display` set so they appear as `table-cell`s ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8yGu/1/)).

### HTML

```
<header>
    <span class="spacer"></span><!-- Place this wherever you want the border -->
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <!-- Spacing is automatically added next to elements (but not on ends) -->
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">View Blog</a>
</header>
```

### CSS

```css
header {
    display:table-row;
    line-height:1.5em;
    font-size:2em;
    white-space:nowrap; /* Prevent titles from wrapping when more than one word is used */
}
header h1 {
    font-size:inherit; /* Change font-size in header */
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
header span.spacer { /* Makes spacers stretch */
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
}
header span.spacer { /* Adds spacing on both sides of spacers */
    padding:0 10px;
}
header span.spacer:first-child { /* Adds spacing only on right side of first spacer */
    padding:0 10px 0 0;
}
header span.spacer:last-child { /* Adds spacing only on left side of last spacer */
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
header span.spacer:after { /* Adds border to spacer */
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    content:".";
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    height:2px;
    background:#000;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
}
header > a { /* Styles links according to example */
    font-size:.4em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#25a2a4;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:monospace;
    border-radius:.5em;
    padding:.3em .5em;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll test that in a second and let you know if it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm. And it's even better solution than the one from link in comments :) The other one required images. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Flow, you're welcome. Be sure to test it in whichever browsers you need to support. It works in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, but I don't have access to anything else at the moment. It should work in all modern browsers, excluding IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the text and the button in a div whose background is set to white? It is hard to tell what you are doing without showing the CSS.

If you are using a div with background, why not just remove it? Or if there is some constraint why not set the background to rgba(#,#,#,0.0)?

```
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
```

The alpha property helps set the level of opacity.

Comment: If the `background` is removed, the border will show through.

Comment: I'm looking for any container structure. Just need an idea. I'm looking for a way to create something like: ----- TEXT ----- so I can't possibly set opacity to 0 because the line will go through the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<fieldset>` tag to accomplish this.

Example: https://jsbin.com/tovuwimezu/edit?html,css,output

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="blogLegend">New Blog Post</legend>

        blog details here
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.blogLegend {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(63, 169, 196);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```