# How to have a horizontal line at the middle of a html heading with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Ok I now use an image to do it, but I want to do it via CSS(no absolut or relative positioning, I'm looking to make it responsive).

Example here: http://teothemes.com/wp/services/. The heading is 'Services', right above the 3 content areas...I'd like to achieve the same effect with only CSS. I tried some things but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Care to show us what you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to position text over border?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142748/how-to-position-text-over-border)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it -> http://tinkerbin.com/QN9efWHd

- CSS3 background-image
- span with background covering the background image.

the HTML...

```
<p>
    <span>Services or Something</span>
</p>
```

... for the CSS...

```
p {
    background: linear-gradient (to bottom,  rgba(145,37,37,0) 49%,
                rgba(145,37,37,1) 51%, rgba(145,37,37,1) 52%,
                rgba(145,37,37,0) 54%);
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This is a separate question- good answer btw, but what if the heading and horizontal line is inside a div with opacity: 0.5; I am trying to create this, but haven't found any solution. I want the opacity to remain consistent throughout if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem you're referring to. Take a look here -> http://tinkerbin.com/VQ9yPQnd . Is it similar to what you want to achieve? The only thing you become dependant on is on changing the spans color to the same color as the background it's directly above.

Comment: Yes, awesome. So, i was using rgba for the background, but it works great when i actually use opacity. Thanks!

Comment: Tinkerbin seems to have disappeared (replaced by a holding page) and I can't get this example to work. Anyone care to re-host the example somewhere like JSfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my go at it... Only thing is the `spans` have a set width.

**HTML**

```
​<div id="hr">
    <span></span>
    asdf
    <span></span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#hr span {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7W7Ee/)

Answer (score 2):

Using one floated span with a border:

```
<div class="heading">
     <span></span>
     <h3>Heading<h3>
</div>


.heading {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;    
}

.heading span {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0 -8px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading h3 {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 0px 0 20px;  
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The negative base margin on the span may need to be adjusted for different heading sizes. , The background colour of the heading should match the background of the overall container.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QVUKJ/)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at a bunch of solutions to this issue, and I really wanted something simple.  Why not just use the `:before` and `:after` to embed some content into the heading you want to have a horizontal-rule/line in.  In my CSS below I chose an EM DASH ([unicode `\2014`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)) for the heading's horizontal line.  When making a larger horizontal line, and depending on your font, you need to take away letter spacing from multiple EM DASHes. Lastly you can add some padding to the head & tail of the *EM DASH* so that it doesn't press up against your heading text.

Here's some CSS, heading-1 is very simple, heading-2 has a longer line (see in action https://jsfiddle.net/pyxkh3jz/):

```
h1:before, h1:after {
    content:"\2014";
}
h2:before, h2:after {
    /* two dashes */
    content:"\2014\2014";
    /* depending on your font adjust this */
    letter-spacing: -6px;
}
/* add some padding so heading text isn't touching lines */
h2:before {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
h2:after {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Haven't checked browser compatibility here; but this isn't radical CSS so it should work for some or most of you.  The lines and their length fit my use case.

This idea can probably be improved upon by other keeners...have at it!