# Add a line next to a header with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-heading

Is there a way to display a line next to a header using CSS? Here's an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

<strike>I could do it with a static background image, but that'd require custom CSS for every heading. And I could do some hacky stuff using `:after` and background colors on the `h1`, but it wouldn't look right against a gradient background.</strike>

I'd like to do this with CSS, not JavaScript. If it doesn't work in older browsers, that's fine.

**UPDATE:**

In the past I've done something like this:

`<h1><span>Example Text</span></h1>`

```
h1 {background-image:url("line.png");}
h1 span {background-color:#FFF;dislpay:inline-block;padding-right:10px}
```

While that works, it's hacky, and it doesn't work well with gradient backgrounds, because the `span` has to have a solid background color.

What I'm really looking for is something like this:

`<h1>Example Text</h1>`
`h1 {background-image:url("line.png");} /* but don't appear under the example text */`

I misspoke about the `:after` thing in the original post, I was thinking of another issue I had in the past.

Comment: Post your HTML.  You may need to add some extra markup to provide an element to contain the line.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you face with :after post some code or fiddle.

Comment: Wouldn't really consider using a pseudo-element as 'hacky'. `:before` and `:after` are powerful for decorative elements such as these.

Comment: _"but that'd require custom CSS for every heading"_ Why? Even if your headings aren't at the same level you could apply the same CSS to multiple elements with a single rule.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/WZtMt/1/

Comment: Sorry, I went out to lunch just after posting. I'll update the original post...

Comment: Why do you think your method is 'hacky'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research, I think I found the best solution:

```
h2 {
    color: #F37A1F;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2:after {
    background: url("../images/h2.png")  repeat-x center;
    content: " ";
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

    h2 > span {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 0 9px 0 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Modified from: [How can I make a fieldset legend-style "background line" on heading text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985009/how-can-i-make-a-fieldset-legend-style-background-line-on-heading-text)

It still requires some extra markup, unfortunately, but it's the most minimal that I've found. I'll probably just write some jQuery to add the `span` automatically to the `h2`s.

Comment: I found a way to do it without wrapping the text in a `span` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="border">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -17px;
    background: #fff;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Here is the **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GD7pR/)** to the above code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way of doing it.

Start with the following HTML:

```
<h1>News<hr class="hline"></h1>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
h1 {
    background-color: tan;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.hline {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: none;
}
.hline:after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Dsa9R/

You can repurpose the `hr` element to add the line after the text.

The advantage here is that you don't have to wrap the text with some other element.

**Note:** You can rewrite the CSS selectors and avoid declaring a class name and save a bit of typing.

Comment: The markup doesn't validate, plus it's no better than just using a span, as it requires additional markup.