# Making a tittle between two lines

Tags: html, css, html-heading

This is probably a simple question but:

How can I make a title using any headling tag but I want the title between to lines like this:

*HTML :*

```
<h4>Staging Server</h4>
```

*Illustration :*

[image: sample]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a line next to a header with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198769/add-a-line-next-to-a-header-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements.

```css
h4 span {
  position: relative;
  color: #00C8FF;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 80px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
h4 span:before, h4 span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 1px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  background: #6F6F6F;
  left: -60%;
}
h4 span:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h4><span>Staging Server</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally the first result on Google...

```css
body
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.subtitle {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
.fancy {
  line-height: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.fancy span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
}
.fancy span:before,
.fancy span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
}
.fancy span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.fancy span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p class="subtitle fancy"><span>A fancy subtitle</span></p>
```

Taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<fieldset style="border:none; border-top: 1px solid #999;">
    <legend style="text-align:center;"> Staging Server </legend>
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3qcpjgxw/

Comment: Also legend can be completely styled so... simple, elegant +1 plus it's a container for whatever you have coming next

Comment: A fieldgroup and legend are not intended to be used as regular content headers, but to identify the controls of a form. You lose the SEO benefit of title tags and, and make the code confusing. Might even confuse screen readers, but I don't know. This is just a misuse of the fieldgroup/legend elements IMO. The OP specifically asked for "using any heading tag" as well. I would not recommend this for a title.

Comment: yes and no, you typically don't have a heading without follow-up content which in this case is likely stats on the "staging server" which *should* in all likelihood be a series of fields and labels.  For myself, working with ASP.NET, there is typically only ever one form.  But a whole lot of controls that need to be organized and compartmentalized and, for me, fieldset/legend is a great tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example could be like this:

```
<hr><h4>Staging Server</h4><hr>
```

And a little CSS tweak:

```
hr, h4 {
  display:inline-block;
}

hr {
  width:30%;
}
```